# Java Generics: Subclassing a generic superclass - is subclass a reifiable type?

Tags: java, generics

I'm reading the SCJP by mughal (3rd edition) (the best SCJP book i have come across) and on page 727, it says the following:

```
class MyIntList extends ArrayList <Integer> {} // A reifiable subclass
```

Now i'm just a bit puzzled here. I do know the subclass is of a non-generic type but since it extends ArrayList <Integer> and the parameterized <Integer> will be erased eventually, and this subclass will inherit properties of it's superclass, why would this subclass MyIntList be a reifiable type?

Comment: How would this distinction matter in this case anyway? It is clear that `new MyIntList().getClass() == MyIntList.class` with no loss of information (because what else could it ever be?) -- does it then matter whether one formally assigns the word "reifiable" to it or not?

Comment: You seem to think that in this case, `MyIntList` would at runtime have its superclass parameter `<Integer>` erased.  This is not the case.  Concrete subclasses of a generic class retain the type information of their superclass's generic parameters.  This makes possible some [rather nifty tricks](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html).

Comment: @Henning, think of all the tooling, testing etc that can be written against a constrained List.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because every instance of `MyIntList` is a `Array<Integer>`, you can find out the lower/upper bounds using reflection.

If you said `class MyNumberList<T extends Number> extends ArrayList<T> { ... }`, you can still find the bounds, but not exactly what `T` was for a particular instance of `MyNumberList`.

Comment: But the parameterized <Integer> has been erased

Comment: @yapkm01: No it hasn't.  Non-generic subtypes of a specific parameterization of a generic type don't have that parameterization erased.

Comment: @yapkm01 one way to build up an intuition for this is to think about *instances*. If you have an instance of `ArrayList`, you don't know what `T` is. But every instance of `MyIntList` is always an `ArrayList<Integer>`. Put another way, Java doesn't create a new `Class` corresponding to your `ArrayList<T>`. But the parameter types are baked into the `Class` for `MyIntList`.

Answer (score 3):

from The Java Language Specification
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html

4.7 Reifiable Types

Because some type information is erased during compilation, not all types are available at run time. Types that are completely available at run time are known as reifiable types. A type is reifiable if and only if one of the following holds:

- It refers to a non-generic type declaration.
- It is a parameterized type in which all type arguments are unbounded wildcards (§4.5.1).
- It is a raw type (§4.8).
- It is a primitive type (§4.2).
- It is an array type (§10.1) whose component type is reifiable.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this scenario is none of the above?  Or if I am missing something, can you please make it explicit in your answer which of these applies here?

Answer (score 0):

The generic type is erased during compilation of ArrayList, but not during compilation of MyIntList. So during runtime you can find out that MyIntList extends ArrayList by calling `MyIntList.class.getGenericSuperclass()` and analyzing the returned object.

The reason why this is possible is that MyIntList itself is not generic, but extends a concrete instantiation of ArrayList. So this information can just be stored in the Class object of MyIntList (from where it is accessible using the method mentioned above).